# Single word to denote "immunity from scrutiny"

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a single word which denotes immunity from scrutiny or criticism? It would be something with mostly negative connotations, implying some dogmatic or intolerantly axiomatic context which excuses a certain idea or idea bearer from being scrutinized.

Comment: Are you looking for unchecked or unbridled?

Comment: not really because those can be set in any context and then specificity would require using a second word

Comment: Slang: Teflon. No criticism sticks to him.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is **[sacred cow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sacred%20cow)**:

> one that is often unreasonably immune from criticism or opposition

Google's definition also explains that this term originated from "the Hindus' respect for the cow as a sacred animal". Hence, anything or anyone which is a sacred cow is seemingly immune to criticism.

Comment: that's pretty close even though i'd prefer something that's not proverbial

Comment: @amphibient  How does this fulfil your "Single word to denote “immunity from scrutiny” " requirement? If you want 'an expression for a person who is immune to criticism', the question is a duplicate.